# can not find fortumo "API KEYS" section

Tags: fortumo

as fortumo documentations says:

> JWT based authentication Before using the JWT based authentication,
>   you will need to add a public key under "API keys" section in your
>   Fortumo Dashboard. Refer to Preparing SSH keys guide on how to
>   generate the public and private key pair.

https://merchants.fortumo.com/integration-and-testing/hosted-dcb/hdcb-security/

but i cant find it on dashboard. but on General Section we have "Secret" down side. is that it? where can i set the fortumo public key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in Fortumo's [documentation](https://merchants.fortumo.com/integration-and-testing/hosted-dcb/):

*Hosted DCB is an on demand payment product. In order to gain access to the product, please contact your account manager.*

If you don't have an account manager, you can get in touch with them [here](https://fortumo.com/contact/).